# Read the contents of nested NSMutableDictionaries?

Tags: objective-c, loops, for-loop, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

Seems simple enough - I'm creating one master NSMutableDic and filling it with more of them.

What's an easy way to access the contents of a dictionary like this? 
Although this isn't Python, perhaps something to the extent of 'taskDict[4]['assignedby']'?

Here's the code which works fine and dandy:

```
int counter = 0;

NSArray *cols = [GetProjectInfo getTaskColumns];    
NSArray *rows = [GetProjectInfo fetchAll:projectName];

NSMutableDictionary *taskDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableDictionary *localDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (int x=0; x < rows.count; x++) {

    NSString *rowData = [rows objectAtIndex:x];

    NSString *colData = [cols objectAtIndex:counter];

    //Assign the values colData(key) and rowData(value) into localDict.
    [localDict setValue:rowData forKey:colData];

    counter ++;

    if (counter >= cols.count) {

        counter = 0;

        //Add the whole localDict to the global dictionary (taskDict)
        [taskDict setObject:localDict forKey:localDict];

        //Reset the localDict so that we can populate it with the next set 
        [localDict removeAllObjects];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@",taskDict);
```

returns something to the extent of:

```
            {
    person = "Ryan";
    assignedby = jfreund;
    complete = False;
    timeassigned = "15:35:00";
} =     {
};
    {
    person = "Tim";
    assignedby = klang;
    complete = True;
    timeassigned = "16:59:07";
} =     {
};
```

Anybody care to throw some ideas this direction?

Comment: It's a little hard to tell how your `NSMutableDictionary` instances are composed; but could the problem be better solved by structuring your data in an object graph rather than working with `NSDictionary`

Comment: At the end of this I was planing on creating a plist then using that as a form of storage and a way to populate views. What do you mean by structuring the data into an object graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question; but rather than store your object graph as nested dictionaries, could you instead use `NSObject` subclasses to encapsulate your data so that you don't have to traverse hierarchies of dictionaries?  For example, (mind you, I know nothing about your application's model layer...) could you break the conceptual model into Project and Task objects, e.g.

```
@interface Task : NSObject <NSCoding>
{
    NSString *_name;
    NSString *_owner;
    NSString *_assignedBy;
    BOOL _complete;
    NSDate *_timeAssigned;
    //  etc.
}
```

And then Projects are, in turn, composed of Tasks:

```
@interface Project : NSObject <NSCoding>
{
    NSString *_name;
    NSString *_dateStarted;
    NSMutableArray *_tasks;
    //  etc.
}
```

It's a more object-oriented way of structuring the application's model layer.  There's nothing about this mechanism that would preclude you from serializing the data to a plist so long as your classes conform to the `NSCoding` protocol.

Comment: Ah, yes this is a much better way of doing things. I was trying to cut a few corners in my approach to get a quick prototype up, ill try and work it out this way though. Thank's for the suggestion.